# Filter results 6 through 10 of 100 with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I see the `limitTo` filter in the docs, which allows me to limit the first 5, or last 5 results, but I want to set where my limit starts so I can show the second set of 5 results.

Is there a built in filter for that?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Since Angular 1.4.0, the [`limitTo` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) takes an optional `begin` argument:

```javascript
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:5:5">{{item}}</div>
```

In older versions, writing a custom filter is fairly straightforward. Here's a naïve implementation based on `Array#slice` (note you pass the first and last index, instead of a count):

```javascript
app.filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return (arr || []).slice(start, end);
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items | slice:6:10">{{item}}</div>
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/vQUsS/

Alternatively, you can simply steal [the entire Angular 1.4.0 implementation of `limitTo`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js):

```javascript
function limitToFilter() {
  return function(input, limit, begin) {
    if (Math.abs(Number(limit)) === Infinity) {
      limit = Number(limit);
    } else {
      limit = toInt(limit);
    }
    if (isNaN(limit)) return input;

    if (isNumber(input)) input = input.toString();
    if (!isArray(input) && !isString(input)) return input;

    begin = (!begin || isNaN(begin)) ? 0 : toInt(begin);
    begin = (begin < 0 && begin >= -input.length) ? input.length + begin : begin;

    if (limit >= 0) {
      return input.slice(begin, begin + limit);
    } else {
      if (begin === 0) {
        return input.slice(limit, input.length);
      } else {
        return input.slice(Math.max(0, begin + limit), begin);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: @bluescreen's answer below (with 20 up votes) is the correct answer here.

Please choose that one.

Comment: kept giving me errors about arr being undefined so i did this 
    arr = arr || [];  
    return arr.slice(start, end);

Comment: I can't get this to with `ControllerAs` notation: http://jsfiddle.net/r9kvaydh/3/

Comment: @SimonH `item in main.items`

Comment: limitTo filter in angular now provides support to define where limits starts from as well

`{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}`

Comment: too bad angular 1.4 is currently just a snapshot

Comment: if you are doing pagination, you could change to slice(arr, start, count) and then return arr.slice(start, start+count)

Comment: in case if you want elements from 'n' to end of array .. you can use `<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:items.length:n">{{item}}</div>`

Answer (score 133):

AngularJS provides that functionality already out of the box. If you carefully read the limitTo documentation it allows you to specify a negative value for the limit. That means N elements at the end so if you want to process 5 results after an offset of 5 you need to do the following:

`<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 10 | limitTo: -5">{{item}}</div>`

Comment: This solution answers the question asked to a tee. But beware, this only works for the 2nd set of results. It will not work for the 1st, 3rd, 4th set or any others. (The first limitTo creates an array with the first 10 items of the source, the second limitTo can then only work within those results.)

Comment: This goes possibly wrong on the last page. Suppose there are 7 items, the first page shows item 1-5, the second page should show items 6 and 7, but here it will show item 3-7.

Comment: `The length of the returned array or string. If the limit number is positive, limit number of items from the beginning of the source array/string are copied. If the number is negative, limit number of items from the end of the source array/string are copied. The limit will be trimmed if it exceeds array.length`  I don't think this answer is right.

Comment: @connorbode why not?! Could you give an example?

Answer (score 38):

I started playing around with customer filters but then found out you can just call `slice` inside of the `ng-repeat` expression:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items.slice(6, 10)">{{item}}</div>
```

Comment: Simplest answer. Thanks! I thought the second parameter was the length, but it was the stopping position apparently.

Comment: This should be at the top

Comment: This is the best answer if you're on Angular 1.2.X or earlier

Answer (score 4):

As bluescreen said, it can be done using only the `limitTo` filter, although dealing with the *last page* problem noticed by Harry Oosterveen needs some extra work.

I.e. using **ui-bootstrap** `pagination` directive properties:

```
ng-model       = page  // current page
items-per-page = rpp   // records per page
total-items    = count // total number of records
```

The expression should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: rpp * page | limitTo: rpp * page < count ? -rpp : rpp - (rpp * page - count)">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a functional example on how to filter a list with offset and limit:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

Offset: <input type="text" ng-model="offset" value="0" /><br />
Limit: <input type="text" ng-model="limit" value="10" /><br />
<p>offset limitTo: {{offset - phones.length}}</p>

<p>Partial list:</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | limitTo: offset - phones.length | limitTo: limit">
        {{$index}} - {{phone.name}} - {{phone.snippet}}
    </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<p>Whole list:</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        {{$index}} - {{phone.name}} - {{phone.snippet}}
    </li>
</ul>   
</body>

</html>
```

The example is based on the [second step of AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02).

Note that the filter for the offset has to be put as the first filter if you want to cover the generic case where the limit is uknnown.

Answer (score 2):

from bluescreen answer :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 10 | limitTo: -5">{{item}}</div>
```

you might also find a scenario where you need **to take N-th item till the last item**, this is another way using limitTo:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:-(items.length-5)>{{item}}</div>
```

negative sign will take as much as items.length from last, then minus 5 inside the bracket will skip the first 5 items

Answer (score 1):

There's a tidier way to do it without having to invoke a filter and will behave more like a paginator:

```
$scope.page = 0;
$scope.items = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" ];
$scope.itemsLimit = 5;

$scope.itemsPaginated = function () {
    var currentPageIndex = $scope.page * $scope.itemsLimit;
    return $scope.items.slice(
        currentPageIndex, 
        currentPageIndex + $scope.itemsLimit);
};
```

And just stick that in your view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in itemsPaginated() | limitTo:itemsLimit">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can just increment/decrement `$scope.page`:

```
$scope.page++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own reusable filter startFrom like so:

```
myApp.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

and then use it in your ng-repeat like so:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom: 5 | limitTo:5
```

That way it is done "in a spirit of AngularJs filters", testable, can have some "extra" logic if needed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@bluescreen's ans and @Brandon's ans are not equivalent.

for example:

```
var pageSize = 3;  
var page = 2;
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

--

```
item in items | limitTo: page*pageSize | limitTo: -1*pageSize
```

produce [2, 3, 4]

```
item in items | slice: (page-1)*pageSize : page*pageSize
```

produce [4]

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic based projects find the solution below:

mainpage.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="My Music">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="track in tracks | limitTo: limit | limitTo: -10 ">
        {{track.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="list"></div>
    <div align="center">
         <button class="button button-small button-positive" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="decrementLimit()">
            Back
        </button>
        <button class="button button-small button-energized">
        {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
        </button>
        <button class="button button-small button-positive" ng-disabled="currentPage >= data_length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="incrementLimit()">
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('musicApp.controllers', []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  console.log('AppCtrl called');
  // $scope.tracks = MusicService.query();

  $http.get('api/to/be/called').then(function(result){
    $scope.tracks = result.data['results'];
    $scope.data_length = $scope.tracks.length;
    console.log(result)
    // console.log($sco pe.tracks.length)
  });

  var currentPage = 0;
  $scope.pageSize = 10;

  $scope.numberOfPages = function(){
    return Math.ceil($scope.tracks.length/$scope.pageSize);
  }

  var limitStep = 10;
  $scope.limit = limitStep;
  $scope.currentPage = currentPage;

  $scope.incrementLimit = function(){
    $scope.limit += limitStep;
    $scope.currentPage += 1
  };

  $scope.decrementLimit = function(){
    $scope.limit -= limitStep;
    $scope.currentPage -= 1
  }

});
```