# Load more data from local array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Question: I had array of objects for ex: listArray[].

```
var listArray =[];
```

in that array i have 1000 objects, i want show 10 objects in table. and below the table

"Load More Data" button. when I click on Load more data button i need show next 10 objects in that table, pervious 10 objects should be scroll up. using AngularJS.

any one please help me.

Comment: Try to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use limitTo:

```
<li ng-repeat="element in listArray | limitTo:limit">
```

Comment: Hi demas, would you please give me explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I am using setTimeout() in this example, but you can skip it and simple increment 'limit' variable value.

Comment: great demus !! one upvote from me!!! Guys dont say thanks rather you can upvote the talent!!!:-)

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps out

```
<table ng-init="start=10">
...
  <tr ng-repeat="element in listArray.splice(0, start)" >
  ...
  </tr>
...
</table>
....
<button ng-click="start=start + 10" ng-disabled="start > listArray.length">Load More Data</button>
```