# retrieving data from an array, starting with specific nth item in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on a project with Angular, and was curious if there is an 'angular-specific' method to acheive this.

I essentially want to retrieve data starting at a specific item in the array, like the 3rd.
You'll see in the html what I was curious if angular provides any type of method or filter.

html

```
  <div ng-controller="bracketsController">
     <div ng-repeat="bracket in brackets  | limitTo: 2" class="bracket-container left" >
      <div>{{bracket.brackets.single.contestant1}}</div>    
      <div>{{bracket.brackets.single.contestant2}}</div>                
     </div>
   <div ng-repeat="bracket in brackets  | limitTo: 2 SOME **Angular FILTER TO START AT 3**" class="bracket-container right" >
      <div>{{bracket.brackets.single.contestant1}}</div>    
      <div>{{bracket.brackets.single.contestant2}}</div>                
   </div>    
 </div>
```

js

```
var bracketsapp = angular.module('bracketsApp', []);

bracketsapp.controller('bracketsController', function($scope){
      $scope.brackets = [
      {
        "brackets": {
            "single": {
                "contestant1": "john doe",
                "contestant2": "jane doe"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        "brackets": {
            "single": {
                "contestant1": "john doe",
                "contestant2": "jane doe"
            }
        }
      },
     {
        "brackets": {
            "single": {
                "contestant1": "john doe",
                "contestant2": "jane doe"
            }
        }
      },
     {
        "brackets": {
            "single": {
                "contestant1": "john doe",
                "contestant2": "jane doe"
            }
        }
      },
     {
        "brackets": {
            "single": {
                "contestant1": "john doe",
                "contestant2": "jane doe"
            }
        }
      }
    ]
   });
```

Thanks for any tips or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the .slice method directly on the array:

```
<div ng-repeat="bracket in brackets.slice(3)" class="bracket-container right" >
```

Besides that though, there is a discussion they are having currently for the next version of angular to support this as a filter. You can follow along here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5355

Comment: ahh very cool. Thanks for the github link as well, would be a cool filter to add

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own filter, has mention here: [Filter results 6 through 10 of 100 with ng-repeat in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

```
app.filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return (arr || []).slice(start, end);
  };
});

<div ng-repeat="bracket in brackets | slice:3:2">{{item}}</div>
```