# Angularjs: filter ngRepeat when using ControllerAs

Tags: angularjs

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) originally asked the question, and includes a popular answer, but I can't find a way of updating the code to work with ControllerAs.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return arr.slice(start, end);
  };
});

app.controller('MainController', function() {
  vm = this;
  vm.items = [];
  vm.start = 0;
  vm.end = 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) vm.items.push(i);
  return vm;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='MainController as main'>
    Start: <input ng-model="main.start"> End: <input ng-model="main.end">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | slice:main.start:main.end">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

checkout this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WECTuWPDHp7hwoB8GUjs?p=preview)

When you work with controllerAs syntax you need to use controller pointer to access its properties and methods.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='MainController as main'>
    Start: <input ng-model="main.start"> End: <input ng-model="main.end">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in main.items | slice:main.start:main.end">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Good catch. The whole `vm = this;` thing though looks bad to me. It's an undeclared (and two letters!) variable to start with....

Comment: yeah.. people get confuse with $scope and controller as syntax. or sometime its just syntax problem..

Comment: Whoops - one too few `main.` Apologies for uninteresting question.