# How can I show next 15 items in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am currently using angular ng-repeat.

When a user clicks a button that says "Next 15", I would like to show next 15 items.
I don't want to pop items from array, I would just like to hide first 15, and limit show to just the next 15.

Also, when the user clicks "Prev 15", I would like to show just the previous 15 items.

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlIndex as vm">


    <ul ng-repeat=" item in vm.items | limitTo: 15 * vm.page
                                 | limitTo: 15 * vm.page < count ? limitTo: 15 * vm.page : 15 - (15 * vm.page - count)"/>
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
<div><button ng-click="vm.next()">Next 15</button></div>
<div><button ng-click="vm.back()">Prev 15</button></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

 3app.controller('ctrlIndex', function(){

    var vm = this;
    vm.numRecords = 15;
    vm.page = 1;

    vm.items = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        vm.items.push('item : ' + i);
    }

    vm.next = function(){
        vm.page = vm.page + 1;
    };

    vm.back = function(){
        vm.page = vm.page - 1;
    };
});
```

Comment: angular version your working with ?

Comment: the version is 1.3.15

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Comment: yes i have read this post, but still couldnt find a solution. it doestn hide items, it just shows 15 and then 15 more and so on. this is not what i am looking for. i can do it if i pop items from array, but also this is not how i want to do it. i need a solution within angular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2JDW77X3evS0XZh8lZoQ?p=preview)

Markup

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlIndex as vm">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index"
      ng-show="(($index < (vm.page * vm.numRecords)) && ($index >= ((vm.page - 1) * vm.numRecords)))">
            <li>{{ item }}</li>
        </ul>

        <div><button ng-click="vm.next()">Next 15</button></div>
        <div><button ng-click="vm.back()">Prev 15</button></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i need to show records from 16 to 30, not from 1 to 30, as your example (and mine :) ) does, that is the whole point of next 15. i dont want to show 30, i just want to show next 15 and hide previous 15...that is the solution i am looking for

Comment: @frontich See updated Plunker. :-) Note that it shows 0->14, 15->29, etc.

Comment: thank you mr camden_kid this is the solution i was looking for. appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will allow you to keep your view tidy and your logic testable:

```
   // controller
   var vm = this;
   vm.numRecords = 15;
   vm.page = 0;
   vm.items = [];
   vm.data = {};
   vm.data.shownItems = [];
   vm.limit = 100;
   vm.maxPages = Math.floor(vm.limit / vm.numRecords);

   for (var i = 0; i < vm.limit; ++i) {
     vm.items.push('item : ' + i);
   }

   vm.data.shownItems = vm.items.slice(0, this.numRecords);

   vm.next = function() {
     if (vm.page >= vm.maxPages) {
       return
     }
     vm.page += 1;
     var begin = vm.page * vm.numRecords;
     var end = begin + vm.numRecords;
     vm.data.shownItems = vm.items.slice(begin, end);
   };

   vm.back = function() {
     if (vm.page <= 0) {
       return
     }
     vm.page -= 1;
     var begin = vm.page * vm.numRecords;
     var end = begin + vm.numRecords;
     vm.data.shownItems = vm.items.slice(begin, end);
   };

// view
<ul ng-repeat="item in vm.data.shownItems">
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u5lcfz1ys5MYb5bDYEoN?p=preview)