# How to use angular built-in directives to display groups of products?

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an SPA using AngularJS, my web page needs to display list of product groups with their corresponding products as below

```
<h1>Product Group 1</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div>Product1 of group 1</div>
      ...
    <div>Product6 of group 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>Product 7 of group 1</div>
</div>

<h1>Product Group 2</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div>Product 1 of group 2</div>
</div>
```

Each `<div class="row">` tag contains at most 6 product elements

With the model is an array of product groups like this

```
[
 {
    title: 'Product Group 1',
    products: [
       'Product 1 of group 1',
          ...
       'Product 7 of group 1' 
    ]
 },
 {
     title: 'Product Group 2',
     products:[
        'Product 1 of group 2'
     ]
 }
]
```

The number of products in each group can be varied, not fixed, it may come from a database data for example

Is this possible to use only Angular built-in directives to display specified model data in order to form a page as described ? 
I have tried with ng-repeat but it seems not to be a solution. I am looking forward to any idea from AngularJS experts. Thanks for your help!

Comment: a nested `ng-repeat` should do all that you need unless you have oversimplified the sample data. What have you tried?

Comment: @charlietfl but that wouldn't be valid for `<h1>Product Group 1</h1>` he should have one more wrapper

Comment: Yes you need two `ng-repeat`s as mentioned.

Comment: @pankajparkar there shouldn't be any need for the extra rows though, that can all be managed by css

Comment: @charlietfl how can ng-repeat will add one row before doing for each>?

Comment: @charlietfl did you looked at html `<h1>Product Group 1</h1>`(has dynamic title) is outside of the div which we are gonna do `ng-repeat`

Comment: If my app is not a SPA, we could archive the above html structure very easy in a full page load and using jstl. I want to find an equal solution on angular, my purpose is to archive the same structure. Look and feel is only part of story, sometime we should deal with a ridiculous requirement

Comment: @ChiếnNghê using ng-repeat you would have an outer wrapper for each main group then products would all be in one `row` per group...and would use css to ignore limit of 6 to a row....or do some DOM manipulation in a directive if that must be adhered to

Comment: or can use `ng-start-repeat` and `ng-end-repeat` to not have outer wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array is called `$scope.groups`, you simply do that:

```
<h1 ng-repeat-start="group in groups">{{group.title}}</h1>
<div ng-repeat-end class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="product in group.products">{{product}}</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: to display products separated into multiple rows you can add some pre-processing. See my snippet below where I compute `rows` by cutting the `products` array into chunks of 6 elements:

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function($scope) {

  $scope.groups = [
   {
      title: 'Product Group 1',
      products: [
         'Product 1 of group 1',
         'Product 2 of group 1',
         'Product 3 of group 1',
         'Product 4 of group 1',
         'Product 5 of group 1',
         'Product 6 of group 1',
         'Product 7 of group 1',
         'Product 8 of group 1'
      ]
   },
   {
       title: 'Product Group 2',
       products:[
          'Product 1 of group 2'
       ]
   }
  ];
  
  $scope.getRows = function(products) {
    var rows = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (products[i]) {
      var n = Math.floor(i/6);
      if (!rows[n]) { rows[n] = []; }
      rows[n].push(products[i]);
      i++;
    }
    return rows;
  };

});
```

```css
.row { margin: 1em; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  
  <h1 ng-repeat-start="group in groups"
      ng-init="rows = getRows(group.products)">{{group.title}}</h1>
  <div class="row"
       ng-repeat-end
       ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div ng-repeat="product in row">{{product}}</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

You have other ways to do "pagination" of your results, and it is even easier if you are usig Angular 1.4, see this answer for more examples:

[Filter results 6 through 10 of 100 with ng-repeat in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Comment: Sorry, with your solution, how could i limit at most  6 products per row? If our model have 7 products, all 7 products will be wrapped in only one row. In this case, i expect we have 2 rows, first row holds 6 products, other holds 1 remaining one

Comment: @ChiếnNghê sorry I missed that part, I have updated my answer with a working code snippet