# AngularJS - Best way to repeat creating cols

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want the following result:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4>
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 1
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 2
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 3
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4>
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 5
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 6
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 7
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 8
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4>
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 9
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 10
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 11
        <input type="checkbox"> Item 12
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have in my controller my variable:

```
$scope.items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", ...];
```

I can't find a clean way (without `ng-ifs`, calculating % of the iteration, etc)  to iterate with `ng-repeat` and get that result. Is there any?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out the following post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:4:0">
          <input type="checkbox" /> {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:4:4">
          <input type="checkbox" /> {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:4:8">
          <input type="checkbox" /> {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a dynamic number of columns, you'd have to calculate the number of columns first. You can do this using `$scope.cols = new Array(Math.ceil($scope.items.length / 4));` in your controller then loop over that using this:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="col in cols track by $index" ng-init="colIndex = $index">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:4:(colIndex*4)">
          <input type="checkbox" /> {{item}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'm finishing my code right now and it does looks a lot like your second code. I'm using Angular 1.2 so I had to implement some filters myself, but yes this is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide it in 3 divs each with 4 checkboxes, you could change your variable like:

```
$scope.items = {"div1":["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"],
                "div2":["Item 5", ..... ],
                "div3":[.........] };
```

then your html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="divs in items">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="checkbox in divs track by $index" value="{{checkbox}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guinn, the thing is that actually my "items" variable is coming from an webservice. I can indeed make some processing on it but I would rather not having to do so.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case cubbuk's link should provide the answer you can work with!