# pagination to array of objects and filtering?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter, pagination

I have a big array of objects coming from facebook api... it's 1000 objects.

Im doing this simple thing:

```
$scope.friendsData = res.data;
```

the res.data is structured like this:

```
 [{
      id   : someid
      name : somename 
   }...]
```

and i have a filter on this ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="friend in filtered = (friendsData | matchnames:search)"
```

(matchnames is a custom filter that returns only what i write in the search model)

I want the following:

For performance reasons of course, i want to display the first 50, and than (if there are more than 50), show a next to show the next 50.

Sounds simple, but when i do the filtering i want to show the filtered array in the same manner, 50 in every "page". ( next and previews shows me the next batch of 50 and the last batch of 50)

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do pagination with the [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter. e.g.

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in (filtered = (friendsData | matchnames:search)) | limitTo: 50 : pageIndex*50"></li>
```

Comment: This one is still not working, in the controller should i have a pageIndex of for say 1? than when i click next it should be 2? cause this solution still not working for me

Comment: angular 1.3 have no begin param in the limitTo, so a custom filter had to be applied.

Comment: Didn't realize that. Here is an example of doing this in older versions of Angular http://stackoverflow.com/a/17756219/373655