# Angular ng-repeat for Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I have an issue where my carousel shows the correct amount of `uib-slides` based on the list (3 items per page so if there are 7 total items there are 3 pages 3/3/1) but instead of the proper 3/3/1 it is showing all 7 items on each page 7/7/7.

**HTML**

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in testCtrl.carouselSlides track by $index" index="$index" ng-class="{active : $first}">
        <div ng-repeat="fav in testCtrl.carouselList">
            <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="f in fav">
                <widget-chart="widget" style="margin:auto;"></widget-chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`carouselSlides` is just an empty array that is calculated to show how many pages is needed. So if there are 8 items it needs 3 pages (3/3/2) so `carouselSlides` just equals `[ , , ]`

`carouselList` is the data which is a formatted to look something like

```
carouselList = [
    [a, b, c],
    [d, f, g],
    [h, i, j],
    [k, l]
];
```

But can be any length it's just put into arrays of 3.

I have tried adding a `limitTo` but it didn't seem to have any effect.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="f in fav | limitTo:3">
```

I tried doing something similar to bluescreen's answer to [Filter results 6 through 10 of 100 with ng-repeat in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796087/filter-results-6-through-10-of-100-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) where I have two limitTo's but it didn't work either.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="f in fav | limitTo:6 | limitTo:-3" >
```

Is there something wrong with what I am doing? Is this even possible with ui-bootstrap's carousel?

---

**=====UPDATE=====**

I tried modifying my code to see if @NTP's solution would work. Here is my attempt.

I reformatted the data in `carouselList` to look like

```
carouselList = [a, b, c, d, f, g h, i, j, k, l];
```

and changed my HTML to be

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in testCtrl.carouselSlides track by $index" index="testCtrl.carouselList[$index]">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <widget-chart="testCtrl.carouselList[$index * 3]" style="margin:auto;"></widget-chart>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="testCtrl.carouselList[$index * 3 + 1] != undefined">
            <widget-chart="testCtrl.carouselList[$index * 3 + 1]" style="margin:auto;"></widget-chart>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="testCtrl.carouselList[$index * 3 + 2] != undefined">
            <widget-chart="testCtrl.carouselList[$index * 3 + 2]" style="margin:auto;"></widget-chart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this did not work.

Note: I am not sure if this matters or not but I am not repeating images I am repeating a widget panel object I have.

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="fav in testCtrl.carouselList">` You are going through all the items all the time. This loop is nested but not using the parent variable.

Comment: Hmmmm I am a little confused by what you mean here?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle where we can see your problem

Answer (score 0):

first calculate number of iterations for ng-repeat

```
  $scope.getNumber = function() {
    if($scope.slides.length % 3 == 0)
      return new Array($scope.slides.length / 3);
    else
      return new Array(Math.floor($scope.slides.length/3) + 1);   
  }
```

then use the following code to display 3 items per slide

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in getNumber() track by $index" index="slides[$index].id">
    <img ng-src="{{slides[$index * 3].image}}" style="width:33%">
    <img ng-show="slides[$index * 3 + 1] != undefined" ng-src="{{slides[$index * 3 + 1].image}}" style="width:33%">
    <img ng-show="slides[$index * 3 + 2] != undefined" ng-src="{{slides[$index * 3 + 2].image}}" style="width:33%">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w41qAqYdBDEQX9KsUYR3?p=preview)

Comment: I don't think this solution would work for me as the amount of slides in your case would only account for up to 9 whereas mine is an unknown amount. Also, I tried using your solution in my updated question just to see if I could get it to work for 9 but it still did not work.

Comment: there is no limitations for number of slides, you can test this by pressing add slide button in given plunker.

Comment: change testCtrl.carouselSlides in your ng-repeat with the getNumber() function